# jQWidgets Grid date format shown as object

Tags: json, date, format, jqwidget

I'm currently working with JQwidgets (jqxgrid) and I have a problem when I want to work with dates. The idea behind is to get a JSON object and from it it should create a table dynamically.

In my JSON object, the date is shown like this:

```
"customer_dateCreate":{"date":"2013-03-05 18:06:27","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}
```

in my JQwidget script, I have the following format:

```
{name: "customer_dateCreate" type: "date"}
```

However, in mygrid the cell is rendered like: [object Object]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customer_dateCreate is actually an object. If you want to make it to point to the Date field, you should use that:

```
 {name: "customer_dateCreate", map: "customer_dateCreate>date", type: "date"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that was exactly the probem!